# How to create HFS partition on Windows 7 machine

Tags: macos, windows, partition, hfs

I've got Windows 7 running on my computer and I would like to partition my `D:` volume, make it HFS+ but I cannot find any tool that will accomplish this.

Anyone had done this before? Is it possible? I have EaseUS partition tool but it does not support HFS/HFS+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know of two commercial tools: [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/standard/) and [TransMac](http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm). They both have limited time trials to evaluate before you buy.

You could also try a Live CD of [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), it has HFS support.

Update: a colleague of mine told me you can create a HFS partition with `diskpart`. Just make sure it's **primary** and use partition id `af` (`create partition primary id=af`).

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I tried trial version of MacDrive but I couldn't format the ntfs volume I suppose it is limited won't let me do it but I will try TransMac it sounds promising. Thanks alot

Comment: @Pinchy - Not sure what *couldn't format the ntfs volume* means. You want to format an existing NTFS partition as HFS? AFAIK you have to delete the NTFS partition and create a new HFS partition in the free space.

Comment: Well, I didn't delete the partition coz I didn't know I needed to delete the partition to see the format options on the volume. I will try that one too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Paragon HFS + for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/), for example. With him will be an opportunity and to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Paragon Partition Manager Free](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/) with which you can do this, to format Windows partitions to Apple HFS+.

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me.

[Paragon Hfs-Ntfs converter.](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/ntfs-hfs-converter/)